# Severity inside logger and inside root interaction

Tags: java, logging, configuration, logback

I have the following logger configuration:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


    <!-- third party loggers-->
    <logger name="org.springframework.web">
        <level value="INFO"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Please explain to me what the reason to write `<priority value="debug"/>` inside the tag and  `<level value="INFO"/>` inside the `logger` tag

How do these values interact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in the `root` is what level is shown by default. The value in the other `logger`s' value is an override for classes in that package, in this case `org.springframework.web`. *(Also, this will be anything in `org.springframework.web` so you can think of it as `org.springframework.web.*` if that helps.)*

[*(Some documentation on logging levels.)*](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Level.html)

The different log levels are

- `OFF`
- `FATAL`
- `ERROR`
- `WARN`
- `INFO`
- `DEBUG`
- `TRACE`
- `ALL` (The difference between this and trace only appears if you have custom logging levels.)

`OFF` and `ALL` aren't levels messages can be, they are levels loggers can be set to. Whatever level the logger is set to it will display messages from each of those levels and lower.

For example, in your case you have `root` set to `DEBUG` and `org.springframework.web` set to `INFO`. All classes except those in the `org.springframework.web` package and its child packages will display everything but `TRACE`, but those inside it them will display all but `TRACE` and `DEBUG`.